# Create() method called multiple times

Tags: libgdx

`Create()` method of my game class is being called in `onSurfaceChanged(GL10,int,int)` and `onSurfaceCreated(GL10,EGLConfig)`.

So whenever the game is interrupted by any thing i.e call,sleep , it restarts .

I cant find any thing ..plz help  .How do i stop this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is happening on `Andorid`, if you rotate your device form profile to landscape mode and vice versa try this:

> Try fixing your orientation in the manifest file and specify that you
>   will handle orientation changes yourself:
>
> `<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape"`
>   `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" ...>`

If `create()` is called if you return after `pause()`, it is probably, because your app was closed by the dalvik VM. Try it on different devices. If the issue stays the same update your question here with relevant test and results. If we can't help you try to write a new issue on their page or ask in the forum.